# Can we represent "self class" in Java (or Kotlin)?

Tags: java, kotlin, subtyping

I think the question title is a little bit confusing, but I can't find a more precise way to say this.
I just need a simple code example to tell you what I want.

I have:

```
// code 1
interface A { A bla(); }
class B implements A { @Override public B bla() { return this; } }
class C implements A { @Override public C bla() { return this; } }
```

But actually, this code will compile too (diff: look at the return type declaration):

```
// code 2
interface A { A bla(); }
class B implements A { @Override public A bla() { return this; } }
class C implements A { @Override public A bla() { return this; } }
```

I want code 2 to be a type error.
Say, I want to force every `A`'s subclass' `bla` method to return their self, instead of an `A`.

I think there can be a fake code to represent what I want:

```
interface A { this.Type bla(); }
```

Just like Haskell's typeclasses:

```hs
class Monad (m :: * -> *) where
  -- here m is restricted to the subclass
  (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Not possible in Java, don't know about Kotlin.

Comment: Oh no, bad news TAT @Oleg

Comment: @ice1000 I've used this library, and I think it is what you are looking for: https://github.com/h0tk3y/kotlin-monads ;)

Comment: @NeilLocketz I opened your link, and see `Unstar` at the top right corner... LOL

Comment: That's Hilarious! hahaha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible, but you can do that

```
interface A<T extends A> { T bla();}
class B implements A<B> { @Override public B bla() { return this; } }
class C implements A<C> { @Override public C bla() { return this; } }
```

Comment: Ah, many thanks! prpr